# BitShifting, Storing 3 u_int8_t in one integer and read out again

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

i have a question for you guys which is driving me nuts for 2 days already. Maybe its because i am missing the basics on bit shifting but somehow i don't get it into my head. What i want is a simple program which reads in 3 char or uint8_t's, stores them into one big int and then reads it out later again.

It is the first time that i experiment with bit shifting, and somehow i am stuck.

This is the code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    u_int8_t insert1;
    u_int8_t insert2;
    u_int8_t insert3;
    int data;

    printf("Please enter value1: ");
    scanf("%d", &insert1);
    printf("Please enter value2: ");
    scanf("%d", &insert2);
    printf("Please enter value3: ");
    scanf("%d", &insert3);

    data |= insert3<<16 | insert2<<8 | insert1;

    printf("\nValue1: %d\n", data);
    printf("Value2: %d\n", data>>8);
    printf("Value3: %d\n", data>>16);
    return 0;
}
```

When i Enter

126
103
255

i get:

Value1: 16711680
Value2: 65280
Value3: 255

Which is completely wrong. I am pretty sure that the value is stored correctly stored into data but i don't know how to read out.

Thanks very much :-)

Comment: You're missing the headers that define `uint8_t`, `printf`, and `scanf`.  In C, they'd be `<stdint.h>` and `<stdio.h>`; in C++, they'd probably be `<cstdint>` and `<cstdio>`, but you might need to refer to the `std` namespace.  Your code looks like it's compatible with pure C; if it's really C++, why aren't you using C++-style I/O (`cout << ...` and so forth)?  If you're using `<stdint.h>`, the type is `uint8_t`, not `u_int8_t`; if not, where is `u_int8_t` defined?  It's helpful to copy-and-paste your *exact* code to avoid typos.

Comment: sorry but they r of course included  :-) i just posted the main function.. otherwise i couldn't even compile right?

Answer (score 6):

You never initialized `data` and you're doing this:

```
data |=
```

Either initialize it to zero or change the line to this:

```
data = insert3<<16 | insert2<<8 | insert1;
```

Comment: Yup, beat me to it. Uninitialized variables contain junk.

Answer (score 6):

You have three errors:

1. you're passing a pointer to a `uint8_t` to `scanf`, but you're using the `%d` conversion which expect a pointer to an `int`; you need to use `%hhd` to tell `scanf` that you are using a storage the size of a `char`, otherwise you risk to corrupt your stack; or you can change your variables to be of `int` type, or better (since the question is tagged `C++`) use the `std::istream` extraction operator (`operator >>`) that is type-safe
2. you didn't initialize `data`, and used the `|=`, thus mixing uninitialized value with your user entered values (which will produce garbage)
3. when using `printf`, you need to mask the high-order bit if you only want to see the low order bits

So, your code need to read:

```
#include <iostream>

static void readvalue(const char* name, uint8_t& outValue) {
    std::cout << "Please enter " << name << ": " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> outValue;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    uint8_t value1, value2, value3;
    readvalue("value1", value1);
    readvalue("value2", value2);
    readvalue("value3", value3);

    data = insert3<<16 | insert2<<8 | insert1;

    std::cout << "Value1: " << (data & 0xff);
    std::cout << "Value2: " << ((data >> 8) & 0xff);
    std::cout << "Value3: " << ((data >> 16) & 0xff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. the mistake was %d in the scanf. i had to change it to %hhd.

Answer (score 0):

I almost sure it should be >>> instead of >>. I also had similar problem. 
Edit: This is correct for Java when you're working with negative numbers, however you won't be able to store easily negative numbers and get them later, since you will have to know when you have a negative or a positive number inside the integer and add if's accordingly.

Comment: That might be a good answer for Java, but C++ doesn't have a `>>>` operator.